# Setting max column amount in highchart column chart type

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to set a max column amount for my Highchart column chart like so

```
xAxis: {
    categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas', 'Kiwi'],
    tickAmount: 3
}
```

Reading the doc it saying using the `tickAmount` to sets your axis amount.

I want my chart to only display three of the xAxis due to space constraints. This needs to happen dynamically so removing the items from the array is not an option.

Here is my jsfidddle http://jsfiddle.net/rjayako/mt4x95rd/1/

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

From the tickAmount documentation:

> This option only has an effect on linear axes. Datetime, logarithmic or category axes are not affected.

And your axis is a category axis.

You could try using tickInterval and some additional calculation to achieve a similar effect:

```
var categories =  ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas', 'Peaches', 'Lemons', 'Apricots']
var tickAmount = 3

//best effort, for tickAmounts > categories.length / 2 it will show all ticks
var tickInterval = tickAmount > 1
    ? Math.floor((categories.length - 1) / (tickAmount - 1))
  : tickAmount == 1 ? categories.length : NaN
```

then

```
xAxis: {
    categories: categories,
    tickInterval: tickInterval
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/peterlgh7/6anq4p8s/

**EDIT:** 
After reading your comment, and given the fact that you want to hide not just the ticks but also the columns, I could not find anything in the documentation. My suggestion remains to just preprocess your data, i.e. filter it. You can sample it periodically, similarly to how tickInterval works, or you could simply take the first n elements, cause maybe it makes no difference to you. You can see both ways here: http://jsfiddle.net/peterlgh7/L9fa1hg9/

But this is all javascript, no highcharts involved.

Comment: Hey Pedro thanks for your help! With your example it looks like it's still showing the series data http://jsfiddle.net/peterlgh7/6anq4p8s/ in between. Is there a way for that to be removed as well? Thanks

Comment: So you don't want to get rid of the ticks, you want to get rid of the columns too... Is that what you are saying?

Comment: Yes that is correct, sorry if I wasn't very clear initially!

Comment: I will check the docs, but I doubt it is supported. I suggest you preprocess your data and leave only what you want to visualize.

Comment: Check out the edit for an example of such preprocessing

Answer (score 0):

You can set `tickInterval: n` to get it to skip every n item in the axis.

```
xAxis: {
    categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas'],
    tickInterval: 2
},
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mt4x95rd/2/

Comment: Hey Barbara thanks for your help! With your example it looks like it's still showing the series data http://jsfiddle.net/rjayako/hyxrs4p0/1/ in between. Is there a way for that to be removed as well? Thanks

Comment: Ah, you want to eliminate the data points, not the axis ticks.  I think Pedro is right and you'll need to preprocess your data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xAxis.max` property to set the maximum index that can be displayed on the x axis. Categories indexes start from `0` and they're subsequent integers.

```
xAxis: {
    categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas'],
    max: 2
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/q9p3b8hw/

**API reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.max